# How can I give players with a level above 200 an effect in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have created a level system where you can level up.
When a player reaches level 200, it should get an effect.

This is my command:

```
/effect @p[scores={Level=200}] jump_boost 1 1 true
```

This effect works at level 200, but at 201, the player loses it. 
How can I give a player an effect with level 200 or above?

PS: should be multiplayer compatible. When 1 player has level 200 and someone else has a lower level, only the level 200 should get the effect.

Answer (score 1):

According to the minecraft wiki, you can do `Level=200..999` and it will work for anyone with a score between 200 and 999. Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard

Comment: Does this work in MCPE?

Comment: you don't even necessarily need ``999`` in there, actually. if you just want to give them it past 200 indefinitely, you can just do ``Level=200..``.